# Use of the word "have"

Tags: grammar, american-english, past-tense, present-perfect, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

In a menu title/button, does "have" need to be used? Is "1" okay or should "2" be used? 
1) People who contacted you in the last 24 hours 
2) People who have contacted you in the last 24 hours 
This is for a website that uses friendly, informal (American) language. It basically goes by native speech, but as I have been living in a non English-speaking country for a while my intuition is a little rusty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *absolutely* needed. In common speech, it's usually eliminated; this is called ellipsis. So, either 1 or 2 are okay.

As you are developing a site that uses friendly, informal American language, I would say, cutting out the "have" would make it seem more informal and relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

For English grammar, they're both fine.  But for clearest [user interface design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_User_Interface_Design) you should use the shorter form (without "have").